# html/bootstrap: chrome padding where it shouldn't

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried unsuccessfully to fix this for the last few days:

the first time I open the page it has some weird padding on the dropdown menu, only happens on chrome (works fine on FFx and IE)

[image: first time opening]

after the first time the page is loaded it loads fine
[image: after the first time]

as you can see on the screenshot I've already put

```
.myCustomNav ul
{
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

the dropdown menu is called like this:

```
<div>
      <ul class="myCustomNav nav">
        <li>
          <a .../>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

any idea what's wrong?

you can test for yourselves on http://istore.titus.biz/lovelovelove/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed

```
.myCustomNav li{ display:inline;}
```

to

```
.myCustomNav li{ display:inline-block;}
```

and it worked, just needed a few extra tweaks to position it then

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to reduce the padding on the dropdown? Then reduce the padding on the following class in your css.

```
 .horizontal-category a:link,.horizontal-category a:visited{  
  color:#96979D;
  padding:4px 6px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-right:1px solid #ec008c;
 /*background:#09C;*/     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Invalid solution** - Comments below

You need to make the `li` for `.dropdown-menu` - `display: block`. This needs to be placed at the bottom of your nav CSS.

CSS

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    display: block;
}
```

If you want to test this do this:

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    display: block !important;
}
```

That should fix it, but do not use `!important` as your solution. Just make sure that the first snippet is below the other dropdown CSS.

Comment: tried that, the only thing it did was add an extra space on the sub-menus:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13954549/pad/pad3.jpg

Comment: ok, i changed `.myCustomNav li{
    display:inline;}` to `.myCustomNav li{
    display:inline-block;}` and it fixed it, but now the menu is a bit too low, how can i pull it up? i already tried messing with the padding and margins but to no avail

Comment: @DarkW Good job figuring it out. The low menu is caused by `.myCustomNav .dropdown-menu {
margin-top: 12px;`, decrease the `margin-top` space.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer when you have it the way you want :)